# Matplot: Interactively redraw axvline?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot of data where I'm adding some axvlines on top of. I need to redraw those axvlines based on the value of a slider. How do I redraw them?

Comment: Can you show the code of the plots that you have done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ax.axvline` returns a `Line2D` object. You can change the x data of that line.

```
line = ax.axvline(x=.5, ...)
line.set_xdata([.7, .7])
```

would move the line from x=0.5 to x=0.7.

Comment: how can I do that with a timer?